# Не получаю ответ от Telegram."Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found"

Tags: telegram-bot, хостинг

Имеется bot, размещен на timeweb, на самом хостинге получен бесплатный сертификат Let's Encrypt. Setwebhook заканчивается успехом:

> Webhook was set

хотя догадываюсь, что это сообщение не гарантирует успешную установку webhook.

Если проверять обновления через `getUpdates` (до Setwebhook разумеется), то все обновы приходят нормально. Но уже после установки webhook, в ответ от Telegram тишина.

`getWebhookInfo` говорит что

> `"url":"https://тут мой url.index.php",`
>   `"has_custom_certificate":false,`
>   `"pending_update_count":17,`
>   `"last_error_date":1511886170,`
>   `"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found",`
>   `"max_connections":40.`

Сертификат проверен на https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html с успехом.

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос, всё в куче

Comment: Добрый день. Вы решили данную проблему?

Comment: нет, пока пользуюсь getUpdates

Comment: Та же проблема. Вы решили свою?

Comment: да, в setcookie нужно было прописывать не полный путь до файла обработчика, то есть index.php, а просто адрес по которому происходит обработка(имя_сайта.ru)